# Databricks Autoloader failling writing the stream to Delta table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

Im using Autoloader to write streams to Delta tables using this line of code

```
df.writeStream.format("delta").foreachBatch(lambda df, epochId: update_insert(df, epochId, cdm)).option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_directory).trigger(availableNow=True).start()
```

and i get the following error.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 649.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 649.0 (TID 2611) (172.20.12.5 executor 3): **org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows**.
    at com.databricks.photon.PhotonWriteStageExec.$anonfun$executeWrite$2(PhotonWriteStageExec.scala:132)
    at com.databricks.photon.PhotonExec.$anonfun$executePhoton$6(PhotonExec.scala:579)
    at com.databricks.photon.PhotonExec.$anonfun$executePhoton$6$adapted(PhotonExec.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2(RDD.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$5(Task.scala:142)
    at com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWith(UCSHandle.scala:99)
    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.$anonfun$runWithAndClose$1(UCSHandle.scala:104)
    at scala.util.Using$.resource(Using.scala:269)
    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:142)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:904)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1713)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:907)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:761)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
**Caused by:** java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow
    at java.lang.Math.multiplyExact(Math.java:892)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.millisToMicros(DateTimeUtils.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.RebaseDateTime$.rebaseGregorianToJulianMicros(RebaseDateTime.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.RebaseDateTime$.rebaseGregorianToJulianMicros(RebaseDateTime.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.RebaseDateTime.rebaseGregorianToJulianMicros(RebaseDateTime.scala)
```

Comment: If you look at your stack trace you see the following line: `**Caused by:** java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow`. I expect you're using some HUGE numbers in there somewhere because to overflow a `LongType` your value needs to be larger than 9223372036854775807.

Comment: so the problem is the data itself and its values? what is the solution to this?

Comment: Well, the start would be to check out which of your columns are of `LongType`. Then, for each of these columns you should think about whether it makes sense for their value to be so large. If it does make sense, you could try using a `DoubleType`. Those can attain much higher values than a `LongType` but they are fundamentally different (not integer values).